# Interest Service Provider change from cpanel to StackCP caused error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"

Tags: php, mysql

After my web hosting provider migrated from cpanel so StackCP, PHP code that connects to a database to get and display information fails. It worked fine before the change.

The error message is "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"

I have exhausted my remedies trying to solve this problem.

The only suggestion that I found was to try "localhost" and ""127.0.0.1," but neither solved the problem.

My web hosting provider replaced "localhost" with "sdb-72.hosting.stackcp.net."

I have isolated the problem to this line of PHP code:

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Where $dsn contains:  "mysql:host = sdb-72.hosting.stackcp.net;dbname=information"

What could be going wrong?

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

$host            = "sdb-72.hosting.stackcp.net";   // also tried "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" both of which did not work
$username        = "XXXXXXXX";
$password        = "XXXXXXXX";
$dbname          = "information";
$dsn="mysql:host = $host;dbname=$dbname";
$options = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
                );

.
.
.

//--------------------
function List_Links($tableName,$idField,$url,$comments,$start)
{

define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
$p1 = __ROOT__ . "/public_html/php/nrcon_config.php";
require $p1;


try
{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE " . $idField . " >= " . $start . " AND " . $idField . " < " . $end . " ORDER BY " . $idField ;
    
    echo "Debug:  " . $dsn . "<BR>";
    // The code fails on the next line.
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Comment: Add `port=3306;` (or the port specified by your service provider) in your $dsn too

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace to the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "No such file or directory" means that the PDO layer is trying to open a **file**. Which means it is trying to connect to a *UNIX socket*, not to a TCP port.

This should **never** happen with a name such as 'sdb-72.hosting.stackcp.net', **unless** your machine is exactly sdb-72.hosting.stackcp.net *and* the resolver somehow maps that to `localhost` (which allows using UNIX sockets); something that however it should never do.

If you're sure that the MySQL database is running on the very same machine where the PHP code is running, then a dirty, dirty trick you can use - but the REAL solution is for the system administrators to fix the configuration, which is not something you can do - is to use a fake address such as "127.0.0.127". This ought not to be mapped to the local UNIX domain, forcing a TCP connection, which is what you want.

The reason why the UNIX socket is not working is that the MySQL configuration is broken - the client and server do not agree on where the UNIX socket *is*, or maybe the server does no longer bind to the UNIX domain.

If the MySQL server is on another machine, and the problem is with the resolver, then try replacing the name with that machine's IP - I'll note in passing that `sdb-72.hosting.stackcp.net` seems *not* to resolve, so there might indeed be something going on there. If it still does not work, I'd triple-check that the PDO command you're sure causes the error is indeed the actual command being executed.

Apart from that, without looking at the server configuration or checking by directly opening a TCP connection to the MySQL server port - which might or might not be allowed by your PHP configuration - there's very little that can be done to get hard facts and diagnose the problem, and we're limited to educated guessing.